# How to connect to a cable Internet service automatically in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, internet

I want to connect to my cable ISP in India automatically. The ISP requires to open a browser page, then open the bookmarked page of their service, provide username and password and keep that page always open till internet is used. While this is no problem for me, it prevents my child and my wife from using the internet effectively.

I have a Netgear N 300 WIFI DSL modem router through which I connect to it. I previously was able to connect with this same modem to BSNL broadband automatically.

Comment: You could write a shell script to do the log in, using curl. In your browser, open the developer tools while on the login page, go to the "network" tab, and then login. Right click on the corresponding request, select "copy as cURL", and put it in a shell script (This is assuming you're using Firefox, other browser will be different). You can the run it by simply clicking on it, or even automatically on boot.

Comment: @JonasCz - Would you be please give the instuctions in detail, particularly "and put it in a shell script"

Comment: To make a shell script, create a new empty text file, put `#!/bin/sh` at the beginning of it, and on a new line, paste the text you copied from Firefox developer tools. Save it, and, in the file manager, right click on it > properties > permissions >, and check "allow executing this file as a program". Then you should be able to double click on it to do the connection. You can add it to your startup applications too, if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Mark that bookmarked page as your homepage, and set your browser to remember username and password. This way, the browser will automatically load your credentials every time you open it. Then set yet another homepage with your favourite search engine (Google, Yahoo, Yandex, etc), so the browser will open 2 homepages in two different tabs every time you open 'the internet'.

You should check your router settings: type the router address in a browser, and check out those settings. I'm sure you can store ISP name and password there. Someone or something must have had your router reset (maybe power outage, power overcharge, nasty cousin, etc)

If this: http://www.netgear.com/support/product/WNA3100.aspx?cid=gwmng#1915 is your product, then check this wizard: http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/23438.

Comment: I was successful to automatically load username and password in firefox. It now requires only a click to login tab. That's good progress. i failed to set router settings and to set another homepage though. Neither I was able to script as per comment of JonasCz.

Comment: Type: `http://192.168.0.1` in the adress bar of your browser. It should open NetGear firmware interface (smart wizard). See the last sentence of my answer.